# soql Expression cannot be assigned

Tags: apex, soql, compile-error

```
list<dnc_suppression__c> dncsup = new list<dnc_suppression__c>();    
dncsup = [
    select
        id, vin__c, DNC_Owner_Ind__c, First_Name__c, Email_Ind__c,
        Campaign_ID_1__c, Campaign_ID_2__c, Campaign_ID_3__c, Campaign_ID_4__c,
        Campaign_ID_5__c, Campaign_ID_6__c, Email_1__c, Email_2__c, Home_Phone__c,
        Phone_Auto_Dialer_Ind__c,Text_SMS_Ind__c, mobile__c, Campaign_Reminders_Ind__c,
        DNC_Vehicle_Ind__c
    from dnc_suppression__c
    where vin__c IN: aset && Campaign_Reminders_Ind__c = true
    OR DNC_Owner_Ind__c = true 
    OR DNC_Vehicle_Ind__c = true
    ];
```

showing "Expression cannot be assigned" for this line

Comment: What is `aset`?  Have you checked that it has a value before you execute the select?

Comment: I see you have `&&` in there, most likely for an and condition, does that compile? I haven’t tried it out myself anytime.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem seems to be your use of `&&` rather than `AND`:

Incorrect:

```
where vin__c IN: aset && Campaign_Reminders_Ind__c = true
OR DNC_Owner_Ind__c = true 
OR DNC_Vehicle_Ind__c = true
```

Correct:

```
where vin__c IN: aset AND Campaign_Reminders_Ind__c = true
OR DNC_Owner_Ind__c = true 
OR DNC_Vehicle_Ind__c = true
```

However, you also need to use parentheses to indicate to the parser if it's `A AND (B OR C OR D)` or `(A AND B) OR C OR D` or some other permutation.